# How to use vuetify@2.0.0-beta7

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I am using vue-cli and vuetify to create a project.

I want to use the latest vuetify2.0.0 beta7.

But I met some problems,

when I type 'yarn start' to preview, it gave many problems,

it seems that there are all problems about css,

and all in `./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/xxx/xxx.sass`,

here is some of them:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VBtnToggle/VBtnToggle.sass

Module build failed:
undefined
   ^
      Invalid CSS after "    @content": expected "}", was "($material-light); "
      in D:\Workspace\VSCode\pr-re\node_modules\vuetify\src\styles\tools\_theme.sass (line 3, column 5)

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VBtnToggle/VBtnToggle.sass 4:14-184 13:3-17:5 14:22-192
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBtnToggle/VBtnToggle.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBtnToggle/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/plugins/vuetify.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I try to update from my exist project and create a new one, and they finally gave me the same problems.

I do this to update(current vuetify version is ^1.5.14):

1. type `yarn add vuetify@2.0.0`, and choose the beta7;
2. migrate some import code from main.js to src/plugins/vuetify.js
3. run dev, and it told me I lost sass-loader, so I type `yarn add sass-loader`
4. run dev again, and I got that problems

I want to solve that css like problems to let me use vuetify for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install `sass`:

```
$ yarn add sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D
// OR
$ npm install sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D
```

Further information can be found in the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases#user-content-upgrade-guide).